# i am displaying account fields using vf .according to profile fields should be display?

Tags: customsetting

Based on profiles fields should be display like system admin can see all the account fields other profiles will see limited fields how can solve this by using custom settings?

Comment: Why not use Field Level Security?

Comment: Here i am writing controller & vf to display

Answer (score 1):

please try below code to find fields which are accessible.

```
public static Account getFields(){

    string sObjectType = 'Account';
    SObjectType schemaType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjectType);
    Map<String, SObjectField> fields1 = schemaType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    List<String> fieldscdm = new List<String>(Account.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet());
    List<String> fields2 = new List<String>();
    for (String field : fieldscdm){
        if (fields1.get(field).getDescribe().isAccessible())
            fields2.add(field.trim());
        //continue your logic after you get accessible fields
    }


}
```

Comment: by using custom setting how we can achieve above task?

Comment: why do you want to use custom setting ?